# Using OpenCV C++ interface do i need to release camera capture created with VideoCapture(int device?)

Tags: c++, c, opencv

The documentation didnt say anything...but this, but cvCapture is a C type.

"
    Note

```
In C API, when you finished working with video, release
 CvCapture structure with      cvReleaseCapture(), or 
use Ptr<CvCapture> that calls cvReleaseCapture() automa
tically in the destructor."
```

I figure VideoCapture is an object though so no right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The destructor for VideoCapture is

```
VideoCapture::~VideoCapture() 
{
    cap.release();
}
```

So it is not necessary to release it.

If you want to release without destructing the object calling the release() method on a VideoCapture object you well get the same effect:

```
void VideoCapture::release()
{
    cap.release();
}
```